# Exclude unit from IntelliJ clean-up code option (the fix for type inference of explicit exceptions in java 8)

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, exception

I would like to exclude a specific line (or minimum sized unit) from IntelliJ's clean-up code option. We need to workaround [this problem with type inference of exceptions](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8054569) which was fixed in Java 9 but we are stuck in Java 8.

The workaround being cleaned by IntelliJ is given by Oracle in the link:

```
- return g(f("Hi", MyException.class));
+ return g(this.<String, MyException>f("Hi", MyException.class));
```

This fix is cleaned up by intellij if you tick clean-up code.

We can push with 'clean-up code' unticked but it has many contributors so someone will eventually tick and undo the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, critically in the code as we do not push changes to our individual IntelliJ configurations.

1. `Alt + Enter` on the greyed out generic (the warning)
2. highlight `Remove all type arguments` and press `right arrow`
3. `Suppress for ...`

For 'method' an annotation `@SuppressWarnings` will appear - this is my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can define formatter markers: Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Enable formatter markers.

Check [Example of using formatting markers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/reformatting-source-code.html)